# Any alternative of mysql_ping for MSSQL?

Tags: php, sql-server, service, daemon

I'm opening the persistent connection with the DB on MSSQL server over an unstable channel and would like to check the connection status before the transaction starts (it is a daemon service which remains always active).

In case of mysql, postgresql I've used the beautiful [mysql_ping](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php) and [pg_ping](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-ping.php) to be sure the connection is OK. **Any ideas who to accomplish it with M$SQL**?

Comment: Why not just try to execute the transaction and reconnect if it fails?

Comment: As @Michael Mior said, you *MUST* check what happened with real query not mysql ping. What if your connection went down after mysql_ping but before transaction? Just use/create a wrapper class for DB connection that will do it for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no built-in function like that for MSSQL. Your best bet would be to run a cheap SQL select such as SELECT <del>GETDATE()</del> NULL on the open connection, catch any SqlException that is thrown, check and re-establish the connection if needed.

Comment: Yes, SELECT null will be cheaper. Thanks @edze